# Rails datetime_select with time zone

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I am writing a simple calendar app and having troubles with time zones. For as many nice Date and Time helpers, action view and active record sure don't play nice with time zones.

I have an appointment model with the appointment_time attribute which is a datetime.

My current issue is editing appointment_time with datetime_select within a form tag.

```
<%= datetime_select :appointment_time, @appt.appt_time,ampm: true %>

def appt_time
  appointment_time.in_time_zone(time_zone) #this is the appointment owners time zone
end
```

gives a select with the current date and time in UTC, not the appointment date and time. `appt_time` does get called and returns the correct date and time adjusted for the time zone.

The docs mention nothing about time zones, what is the best way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with your select tag, not the time zone offset.  Looks like you want

```
<%= datetime_select "appointment", "appointment_time", default: @appt.appt_time, ampm: true %>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Hopefully that will work on production as well. Playing around with it, what is in the first two arguments don't seem to matter at all. It work just as well with "appt_time" in the first two arguments. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked out.  You may also want to set the Time.zone method in your application controller. If you set Time.zone  =  'Hawaii'  then subsequent calls that return a datetime object will automatically apply the specified timezone offset.

Comment: The first two parameters will count when you want to update - they need to map correctly to object and method in your params hash.