# How do I display Central Standard Time (CST) in my Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### UTC Time Display

I'm working on an application (training class app) that currently saves and displays the training class start date time as UTC.

**Migration**

```
class CreateTrainingClasses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :training_classes do |t|
      t.datetime :starts_at
    end
  end
end
```

**Date Time Select**

[image]

**Date Time Display**

[image]

### Local Time Display (Failed)

However, I want to save and display local time (CST). I've updated the date time select form field to display the desired local time.

```
<%= form.label :starts_at %>
<p><%= form.datetime_select :starts_at, default: Time.now.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)"), ampm: true %></p>
```

[image]

And I've updated the display to show local time. However, it is now showing the wrong time—even when I create a new training class.

```
<td><%= training_class.starts_at.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p") %></td>
```

[image]

### Question

How do I save and display the correct local time for both the form and the class display?

### References

- [Rails datetime_select with time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100538/11809808)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set time_zone in `application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

Then restart server

*Reference:* https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Comment: Important : add `config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc` to save in utc in database ! (always save in utc !)

Comment: @LolWalid UTC is already default. check this url: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

I would say neither. I don't know the Ruby syntax, but why not persist the time zone data with the time itself? This is how it's implemented in SQL Server for comparison:

"The DateTimeOffset structure represents a date and time value, together with an offset that indicates how much that value differs from UTC. Thus, the value always unambiguously identifies a single point in time."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime#the-datetimeoffset-structure